# How can I ignore a parameter in a URL?

Tags: swift, url, decode

My app decodes URLs and I've noticed that when it hits an "&", the process stops and ignores the rest of the URL. It appears that URLComponents is breaking up the URL into pieces - my required parameter and the one that it believes to be a parameter.

```
 hxxp://www.g.com/url?u=http://a.com/test&d=another
  - scheme : "hxxp"
  - host : "www.g.com"
  - path : "/url"
  ▿ queryItems : 2 elements
    ▿ 0 : u=http://a.com/test
      - name : "u"
      ▿ value : Optional<String>
        - some : "http://a.com/test"
    ▿ 1 : d=another
      - name : "d"
      ▿ value : Optional<String>
        - some : "another"
```

What I need from above is the full URL after "u=".

Here is the initial call to the function that decodes the string:

```
if (fullDecode.contains("?u=")) {
            initialDecode = getQueryStringParameter(urlToAttempt: fullDecode, param: "u")!
```

Here is the function that returns the decoded string:

```
func getQueryStringParameter(urlToAttempt: String, param: String) -> String? {
        guard let urlDecoded = URLComponents(string: urlToAttempt) else { return nil }
        print(urlDecoded)
        return urlDecoded.queryItems?.first(where: { $0.name == param })?.value
    }
```

For this code, if the url was "http://www.g.com/url?u=http://a.com/test&d=another", it would return "http://a.com/test" - everything else is stripped away. I'd like it to return "http://a.com/test&d=another"

Is there a way that I'm able to do this with URLComponents, or do I need to do custom code to support this?

*Update*
If I change the url that's being passed to " hxxp://www.g.com/url?u=http://a.com/test%26d=another", URLComponents returns the full url back with the &d=another intact. I'm now going to try to percent encode the special character before sending to the function and see if that fixes the issue.

*Second Update*

Here is a heavily modified type of link I need to decode:

```
hxxps://ue.pt.com/v2/url?u=https-3A__oe.le.com_-3Fauthkey-3D-2521IB-2DCRV-2DqQ88-26cid-3DBACDF2ED353D-26id-3DBACDF2EFB61D353D-2521549-26parId-3Droot-26o-3DOneUp&d=DwMGaQ&c=WNpQK9bFmT89misLWAzsd66s44iGV-VujF_o4whjrfc&r=Ej_UhLznQMBqt3H3IYBQkjyx4xqdnS9mLiYA&m=HOBrLfxamFr4PYdACIR-A49th_oIe3MW69N7X-E&s=bXWSJ8gaSbKSlNuIf30S7Qsa6RcMKA-EOvP577XUyq0&e=
```

These links are generated, which is why I have no control of how the link is built. I need to be able to decode this link to a legible URL. I have dictionaries for the special obfuscation like "-3A__" is "://" Where the above fails is where you see &d=DwM... It's not encoded, and that's where URLComponents is failing:

```
https://oe.le.com/?authkey=!IB-CRV-qQ88&cid=BACDF2ED353D&id=BACDF2EFB6353D!549&parId=root&o=OneUp
```

Does this help?

Comment: The behavior seems logic. I read: http://...url...?key1=param1&key2=param2, where key1 = u, param1 is http://a.com/test, key2 = d, and param2 = another. How are we supposed to know that "&key2=param2" is not a new param, but inside the param1? Missing some escaping I guess.

Comment: Url-in-url should be [percent encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

Comment: @Rob - The url is really just that. It's not percent encoded at all. I could percent encode it either before it gets to the function, or in the function, but I'm not sure that's going to solve the &d still being seen as a parameter to URLComponents

Comment: Also, `http://a.com/test&d=another` — is not valid URL, like it's query is not valid: it should start with `?` not `&`. So, `URLComponents` parses it only way it may be right.

Comment: You say you have a dictionary that converts `-3A__` to `://`. I bet your dictionary has an entry that converts `-3F` to `?`, doesn’t it? Your omission of the `?` sent a lot of us down the wrong road.

Comment: I guess I don't understand. I never said I had an issue with ? - it was always the ampersand (&)

Comment: My issue is resolved, but it was because of all of the answers here and there wasn't one answer that did it all. I ended up just adding code to replace the '&' with %26. Now it's decoded correctly, and I was overthinking it.

Comment: By the way, whomever decided to encode the URL this way deserves a stern rebuke. This is unforgivable, when there are established standards for how URL parameters should be encoded. This is an incredibly fragile solution and deviates from established standards for no good reason.

Comment: “I guess I don't understand. I never said I had an issue with ? - it was always the ampersand (&)” ... The URL you provide in your revised example has a `-3F` (which is a `?` within the URL contained within the `u` parameter, but which is missing from your original example). The issue here is the confusion between which parameters go with which URL (the main URL, or the URL buried in the `u` parameter) and the missing `?` is key to interpreting what’s really going on. Bottom line, don’t worry about it, as your revised example makes it absolutely clear what’s going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your revised question, you give us a URL of the following:

```
let string = "hxxps://ue.pt.com/v2/url?u=https-3A__oe.le.com_-3Fauthkey-3D-2521IB-2DCRV-2DqQ88-26cid-3DBACDF2ED353D-26id-3DBACDF2EFB61D353D-2521549-26parId-3Droot-26o-3DOneUp&d=DwMGaQ&c=WNpQK9bFmT89misLWAzsd66s44iGV-VujF_o4whjrfc&r=Ej_UhLznQMBqt3H3IYBQkjyx4xqdnS9mLiYA&m=HOBrLfxamFr4PYdACIR-A49th_oIe3MW69N7X-E&s=bXWSJ8gaSbKSlNuIf30S7Qsa6RcMKA-EOvP577XUyq0&e="
```

Clearly `-3A__` is `://`, `_-3F` is `/?`, `-26` is `&`, `-3D` is `=`, etc. So if you do:

```
let replacements = [
    "-3A__": "%3A//",
    "_-3F": "/%3F",
    "-26": "%26",
    "-3D": "%3D",
    "-2D": "%2D",
    "-25": "%25"
]

let result = replacements.reduce(string) { (string, tuple) -> String in
    return string.replacingOccurrences(of: tuple.key, with: tuple.value)
}

let components = URLComponents(string: result)!
for item in components.queryItems! {
    print(item.name, item.value!)
}
```

You end up with call to `hxxps://ue.pt.com/v2/url` with the following parameters:

```
u https://oe.le.com/?authkey=%21IB-CRV-qQ88&cid=BACDF2ED353D&id=BACDF2EFB61D353D%21549&parId=root&o=OneUp
d DwMGaQ
c WNpQK9bFmT89misLWAzsd66s44iGV-VujF_o4whjrfc
r Ej_UhLznQMBqt3H3IYBQkjyx4xqdnS9mLiYA
m HOBrLfxamFr4PYdACIR-A49th_oIe3MW69N7X-E
s bXWSJ8gaSbKSlNuIf30S7Qsa6RcMKA-EOvP577XUyq0
e
```

The key here is that the parameters `authkey`, `cid`, `id`, `parId`, and `o` are for the `oe.le.com` URL, but all the other parameters, `d`, `c`, `r`, `m`, `s`, and `e` are *not* part of the URL encoded as part of `u`, but rather are separate parameters for the `ue.pt.com` URL. You do not want to include them as part of the URL for `oe.le.com`.

My original answer is below.

---

Let’s try approaching this problem from the other direction.

Consider these two scenarios where I’m building a URL. In the first, I have a single parameter to `g.com` which is `u`, which is a URL that has parameters:

```
var components = URLComponents(string: "http://g.com")!
components.queryItems = [
    URLQueryItem(name: "u", value: "http://a.com/test?d=foo&e=bar")
]
let url = components.url
```

You’ll see that url is

> `http://g.com/?u=http://a.com/test?d%3Dfoo%26e%3Dbar`

Note that the `=` and the `&` are percent escaped as `%3D` and `%26`, respectively because they are parameters to the URL buried inside the value associated with the `u` parameter, not actually parameters of the `g.com` URL itself.

The alternative scenario is that `g.com`’s URL has three parameters, `u`, `d`, and `e`:

```
var components2 = URLComponents(string: "http://g.com")!
components2.queryItems = [
    URLQueryItem(name: "u", value: "http://a.com/test"),
    URLQueryItem(name: "d", value: "foo"),
    URLQueryItem(name: "e", value: "bar")
]
let url2 = components2.url
```

That yields:

> `http://g.com/?u=http://a.com/test&d=foo&e=bar`

Note that the `=` and the `&` are not percent escaped because they are parameters of `g.com` URL, not parameters of the `a.com` URL contained with the `u` value.

You appear to be giving us a URL like generated by the second scenario, but insisting that it really is like the first scenario. If that’s true, the original URL has not been percent encoded correctly and is invalid. More likely, the second scenario applies and the parameters are of the `g.com` URL, not intended to be part of the `u` value.

---

For what it’s worth, note that you’ve given us a URL of:

> `hxxp://www.g.com/url?u=http://a.com/test&d=another`

If `d` was really a parameter of the `a.com` URL, that URL would be `http://a.com/test?d=another`, not `http://a.com/test&d=another` (Note the `?`, not `&`.)

So this is further evidence that the `d` parameter is really a parameter of the `g.com` url, and that the `u` parameter really is just `http://a.com/test`.

Comment: I edited the question to add a real scenario on how I'm using this. With the URLs I receive, not all of the special characters are encoded. For some reason, I'm trying to percent encode the ampersand now before sending to the function and it's not working. I'm still working with it. Thank you for all of your help so far!

Answer (score 1):

`URLComponents` is parsing your url properly in this case.

`&` in the url query can and could ever belong to the outer `URL`, because inner `URL` doesn't even starts query section(it doesn't have `?` there).

So `hxxp://www.g.com/url?u=http://a.com/test&d=another` is parsed as:

```
  - scheme : "hxxp"
  - host : "www.g.com"
  - path : "/url"
  ▿ queryItems : 2 elements
    ▿ 0 : u=http://a.com/test
      - name : "u"
      ▿ value : Optional<String>
        - some : "http://a.com/test"
    ▿ 1 : d=another
      - name : "d"
      ▿ value : Optional<String>
        - some : "another"
```

But `hxxp://www.g.com/url?u=http://a.com/test?d=another` (`&d` replaced with `?d`) is parsed like

```
- scheme: "hxxp"
- host: "www.g.com"
- path: "/url"
▿ queryItems: 1 element
  ▿ u=http://a.com/test?d=another
    - name: "u"
    ▿ value: Optional("http://a.com/test?d=another")
      - some: "http://a.com/test?d=another"
```

And here you got all your inner `URL` in `u` query param.

Comment: The interesting question will be if the inner URL associated with `u` parameter of the outer URL was `http://a.com/test?d=Foo&e=Bar`.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have control of what the value is that I'm decoding. The url that I receive may or may not have a &<character>= in the URL. If it doesn't, the application works fine. I need to be able to either send the url to the function already percent encoded, or ignore the ampersand in the url from urlcomponents if it exists.

Comment: @Nutrion, you can do nothing about it then without breaking the standard

Comment: @Rob, checked it, outer url would think `e` is it's parameter. So inner url should use percent encoding if it has plans for that query param.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your URL string with "?u=" as a separator and get the second array element using [this function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1413214-components)

Otherwise, you can loop on all your queryItems and concatenate them.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post what I did to correct this, but all of the answers that were submitted helped lead me down this road. The code that sends to the function looks like this:

```
if (fullDecode.contains("?u=")) {
    fullDecode = fullDecode.replacingOccurrences(of: "&", with: "%26")
    initialDecode = getQueryStringParameter(urlToAttempt: fullDecode, param: "u")!
```

If the uitextview fullDecode contains "?u=", then I know there is text in the view. The text should be a fully obfuscated URL, and if it contains an "&", I manually convert it to %26. This is sent to the URLComponents function BEFORE I do my other conversions using my custom dictionary.

```
   func getQueryStringParameter(urlToAttempt: String, param: String) -> String? {
        guard let urlDecoded = URLComponents(string: urlToAttempt) else { return nil }
        return urlDecoded.queryItems?.first(where: { $0.name == param })?.value
    }
```

I was really overthinking this one.

Comment: I do not think this is correct. Look at your URL. You’ve got those `-26` sequences within the `u` parameter. Those should be replaced with `%26`, but the existing `&` should *not* be changed to `&26`. See [my revised answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56396499/1271826).

Comment: Yep, I know this is confusing. But the source I receive these from doesn't appear to always rewrite the & with %26 which is where the issue is. The problem is I rely on the function with URLComponents to do the heavy lifting for the things it can, and I send the remainder to the other function to rewrite the values with my custom dictionary. The URLComponents function is not sending back the full URL to work with which is where my issue was. Everything appears to work the way it's intended now, but I have to encode the special characters if they exist before sending to urlcomponent function.